# jqgrid filter search but cut off

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I am having an issue with my jqgrid search filter toolbar. It appears with the filter fields cut off.

[image]

I tried increasing the height in ui.jqgrid.css ...

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table { padding: 0; border: 0 none; height:20px; width:100%;}
```

and that does give the search table more height but all the inputs are pushed lower and hance become even more cut off.

[image]

Can anyone give me some advice on what to do here? Up until today I was using jqgrid 3.7 with jquery ui 1.8.6 and it looked okay. But today I updated my jqgrid version to 4.6.0 and I've since been getting this issue.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following CSS rules

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-toolbar th {
    height: auto;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-table {
    height: auto;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-input input,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-input select,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-input textarea {
     margin: 1px 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

It could be that you can improve the look of filter toolbar additionally by adding some additional rules with `margin` or `padding`. I suppose that some other CSS rules of your project will be applied to the filter toolbar, but it's difficult to suggest a CSS rule because one can't analyse any your demo.